# Symfony + Composer update history

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php

I'm using composer to update symfony bundles,
after updating all bundles, I'm getting some errors and I'd like to restore the previous versions, the problem is that on my composer the version are like 2.*, so I don't know which version there where before.

Is there any composer history/log file where can I see the previous versions of all my bundles?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

look at composer.lock.
After installing the dependencies, Composer writes the list of the exact versions it installed into a composer.lock file. This locks the project to those specific versions.

http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file

Answer (score 0):

If you commit your composer.lock file (as you should), then if you have problems after an update you can just do `git checkout composer.lock && composer install` which will restore things to the way they were before.